# GCC technical details

Tags: gcc

I don't know if this is the right place for things like this, but I am curious about a few aspects of the GCC front-end/back-end architecture:

1. I know I can compile `.o` files from C code and link them to C++ code, and I think I can do it the other way round, too. Does this work because the two languages are similar, or because the GCC back-end is really language-independent? Would this work with ADA code too? (I don't even know if that makes sense, since I don't know ADA or if it even has "functions", but the question is understood. If it makes no sense, think "Pascal" or even "my own custom language front-end")
2. Where would garbage-collection be implemented? For example, a Java front-end. The way I understand, if compiling to a JVM back-end, the "platform" will take care of the GC, and so the front-end needs not do anything about it, but if compiling to native code, would the front-end send garbage-collecting GENERIC code to the back-end, or does it turn on some flag telling the back-end to produce garbage-collecting code? The first makes more sense to me, but that would mean the front-end produces different output based on the target, which seems to miss the point of the GCC's front-end/back-end architecture.
3. Where would language-specific libraries go? For instance, the standard Java classes or standard C headers. If they are linked in at the end, then could a C program theoretically call functions from the Java library or something like that, since it is just another linked library?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, the backend is at least reasonably language independent. Yes, it works with [Ada](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GNAT).
2. [GCJ](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/) generates native code which uses a runtime library. The garbage collector is part of the runtime library.
3. GCJ implements the [CNI](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcj/About-CNI.html), which allows you to write code in C++ that can be used as native methods by Java code -- but being able to do this is a consequence of them having designed it in, not just an accidental byproduct of using the same back-end.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is possible because calling convention is compatible, but name mangling is different (no mangling in C). To call C function from C++ you should declare it with `extern "C"`. And to call C++ function from C you should declare it with mangled name (and may be with additional or different type args). The calling Fortran code is possible in some cases too, but argument passing convention is different (pass by ref in Fortran).
   There were actually a converters from C++ to C (cfront) and from fortran to c (f2c) and some solutions from them are still used.
2. garbage-collection is implemented in run-time library, e.g. boehm. Backend should generate objects compatible with selected GC library.
3. Compiler driver (g++, gfortran, ..) will add language-specific libraries to linking step.